# How to customize date-fns's formatDistance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, date-fns

I get the date from the backend in this format 2022-10-20T10:41:31.095
How can I customize the date?
example
today: 22:15
yesterday: yesterday 13:45
Week: Friday 14:40
a month or more: 10/27/2007

```
 const distance = formatDistance(new Date(), new Date(wroteTime), { locale: uk });
```

Comment: Do not limit yourself with just date-fns package. Maybe there is something better for this rather than date-fns

Comment: I'm new to React, can you tell me what library is this?